# Achieve these if's in a formula? (Obj-C)

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, design-patterns, formula

I really hate using if's inside my app and I thought this is a pretty straightforward pattern so is there any way to turn the below code into a 1 line formula just for better readability inside my app?

This is the code:

```
int duration = 0;
    if (score < 100) {
        duration = 2;
    } else if (score >= 100 && score < 200) {
        duration = 3;
    } else if (score >= 200 && score < 300) {
        duration = 4;
    } else if (score >= 300 && score < 400) {
        duration = 5;
    } else if (score >= 400 && score < 500) {
        duration = 6;
    } else if (score >= 500) {
        duration = 7;
    }
```

I myself am not that good at math or with coming up with formulas for that matter so would anybody be able to help me get a formula to achieve what the code above does?

Thanks!

Comment: You have overlapping conditions. If `score == 100`, what should happen? Should `duration` be `2` or `3`? The intent of your code is ambiguous (although the value will end up being `2` since only the first condition will be evaluated).

Comment: switch case can be used but again it is not a single line code

Comment: What's the score meant to be if it's between 300 and 400? Has that been missed out on purpose?

Comment: Sorry guys, I updated the code with the right ifs

Comment: Sorry once again, mistyped it. I updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we can rewrite this as follows:

```
int duration = MIN(2 + (score / 100), 7);
```

Am I missing anything? :-/

**EDIT** if score might be negative, we have to add one more cap:

```
int duration = MAX(MIN(2 + (score / 100), 7), 2);
```

**EDIT 2** to symmetrically handle negatives, you can use the following:

```
int duration = MIN(2 + (abs(score) / 100), 7);
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve my code but compatible with negatives numbers too? They would be the exact same checks except score may be negative. I know I didn't ask for this in the original question but I realized that in my game the score can be negative too.

Comment: Sure thing, what layout would you like to have for negatives?

Comment: Same as what I originally posted but except the checks for the positive score values, they would be negative values. The duration isn't affected by this.

Comment: In case the duration should be 2 for any negative number - just use the second snippet from my answer, it would yield 2 for anything lower than 100 (including negatives), 2 to 7 according to your layout for anything below 500 and 7 for anything above.

Comment: The duration wouldn't be 2 for any negative number. The would still abide by the checks I showed above but just for the same score values except negative. So >= -100 && < -200 etc..

Comment: Please see my edit above. It yields 2 for (-100..100), 3 for (-200, -100] and [100, 200) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It's something close to (aka this is untested):

```
-(int) duration:(int) score {
    score = (score > 500) ? 500 : score; // over 600 == 600
    return (score+100)/100 + 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
duration= 2+ (int)(score-100)/100 + score<100? 1:0 ;
```

Comment: True, but I got habit of that.I'll replace it with a more readable notation.

Comment: Oh, I also use if all over the places, as wel as checking for nulls with if (!x) :)